# Sending Arrays from one application to another

Tags: jsp

i want to send 2 arrays from my application to another application. 
i am using the following code

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://bdln2459:50000/pg.com~prf~scprf~dc_pte_sbuyer/PTEMain.jsp",
    type:"post",
    data: {"guvArray":guvArray,"vendorCodeArray":vendorCodeArray}
success: function(){
    alert("success");                             
}

});
```

And am accepting in other application jsp PTEMain.jsp like below

```
String[] arr1= request.getParameterValues("guvArray[]");
String[] arr2= request.getParameterValues("vendorCodeArray[]");
```

When i try to print these arr1 and arr2 i am getting null . do i have to do any mapping in web.xml. please help

Comment: if i am not wrong then you need not to use "[]" after parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

these are browser-based application. the content of the page will not be automatically updated unless  you use some technology like `ajax` that can retrieve values from your database without re-executing your jsp code.

you are using this URL

```
"http://bdln2459:50000/pg.com~prf~scprf~dc_pte_sbuyer/PTEMain.jsp"
```

so i assume that you are using scriptlet.

```
<%
String[] arr1= request.getParameterValues("guvArray[]");
String[] arr2= request.getParameterValues("vendorCodeArray[]");
%>
```

so what is happening in your jsp page is that. right after it execute all the code inside your jsp page, it is done. unless you refresh the page.

one way i think that can help to achieve what you want is to send the data to your controller, in your controller try to save it in a repository(database maybe) or other types of repository, OR just for debugging purposes use a `static` field just to check if the data is reaching its destination.

the url can be like this:

```
"http://bdln2459:50000/pg.com~prf~scprf~dc_pte_sbuyer/servlet url mapping/servlet name"
```

and in your servlet/controller:

```
static String[] arr1;
static String[] arr2;
```

in your doPost method() or in your function (if you're using spring)

```
public void receiveData(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){

    arr1= (String[])request.getParameterValues("guvArray[]");
    arr2= (String[])request.getParameterValues("vendorCodeArray[]");

    request.getSession().setAttribute("guveArray[]",arr1);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("vendorCodeArray[]",arr2);
}
```

if you will be using the dispatch

```
public void receiveData(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){

        String[] arr1 arr1= (String[])request.getParameterValues("guvArray[]");
        String[] arr2= (String[])request.getParameterValues("vendorCodeArray[]");

        request.setAttribute("guveArray[]",arr1);
        request.setAttribute("vendorCodeArray[]",arr2);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("jsp page").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: can i use only request.setAttribute("guveArray",arr1); and dispatch like this   RequestDispatcher dispatcher =     request.getRequestDispatcher("/PTEMain.jsp");
 dispatcher.forward(request, response);

Comment: in this case you need to put it in a session. because you are not dispatching the request to another page, meaning it will still be null.

Comment: since you're sending it from different application. the 2nd application doesn't trigger itself. let me give you an example, if you  send the data in 2nd application it doesn't automatically open the 2nd application.

Comment: you might want to read [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html)

Comment: now i am doing this way as u suggested $.ajax({
        url:"http://bdln2459:50000/pg.com~prf~scprf~dc_pte_sbuyer/receivescf",
        type:"post",
        data: {"guvArray":guvArray,"vendorCodeArray":vendorCodeArray},
 success: function(){
        alert("success");                             
    }
   
 });  onclick of a button i am coming to this function and redirecting to http://bdln2459:50000/pg.com~prf~scprf~dc_pte_sbuyer/PTEMain.jsp page and mapping is done in 2nd applications web.xml for the servlet url

Comment: if you are being redirected you can use the dispatch then